# Error: "Smart cast to string is impossible because "message" is a mutable property"

Tags: android, kotlin

I know that this type of question is already asked but it is not working for me so please tell me how to get the below code working:

```
 if (a1!= null && a2!= null && message != null) {
     if (intent!= null) {
         Thread.sleep(5000)
         ChangePicAsyncTask(context, message).execute(a1, a2)           //Error line 
     }
 }
```

Here "message" is the declared as private var class level nullable variable. Below line "Thread.sleeep(..)" it shows that error. I tried to put an if check but its also not working so please give some suggestions how can i solve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `message` could have been changed (eg become null) after the `Thread.sleep()`. So perhaps use let.

`message?.let { 
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    ChangePicAsyncTask(context, it).execute(a1, a2)
}`

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that it doesn't change, you must assign it to a final variable, like so:

```
 val a1 = a1
 val a2 = a2
 val message = message
 if (a1 != null && a2 != null && message != null) {
     if (intent!= null) {
         Thread.sleep(5000)
         ChangePicAsyncTask(context, message).execute(a1, a2) // Smart casts now work
     }
 }
```

If that seems tacky, then you could use the approach [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50747304/2413303).

Comment: `val a1 = a1` `val a2 = a2` `val message = message` does this compile?

Comment: @mTak yes, why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: Why? What does `val a = 0` `val a = a` mean?

Comment: Assign the value to a final variable (so `val`).

Comment: But it's the same name `a` for 2 variables?

Comment: It's `a1` and `a2` which is clearly two different names?

Comment: The assignment is val a1=a1. This means assigning the value of previously declared variable a1 to a new declared variable by the same name a1 in the same scope

Comment: What you don't understand is *I did not ask you*. This was way to tell you you made a mistake. I knew this was wrong and I expected from you to correct it. As for the part *without me possibly knowing that* you could ask for clarification. As for the part *Learn the language* I have to admit that I'm still learning and not trying to find excuses for my mistakes.

Comment: Not to mention, this ***is*** the right way of doing it if you have multiple mutable field variables.

Comment: It's not my fault the question provided incomplete code. I will stop caring about this nonsense beyond this point. I've already spent way too much energy on an unnecessary flame war anyway.